# Anchor point in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uikit, swiftui

I'm playing with `SwiftUI` animations. I wanted to make a square bigger modifying its frame with an animation this way:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let squareWidth = CGFloat(100)
    let squareHeight = CGFloat(100)

    @State private var bigger = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Color.green
                .frame(width: bigger ? self.squareWidth * 2 : self.squareWidth, height: self.squareHeight)
                .animation(.default)
            Button(action: {
                    self.bigger.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Click me!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The animation happens from the centre of the View, that is the anchor point (0.5, 0.5). Is there a way to change this anchor point? I found out that I can use `scaleEffect` on the view specifying an `anchor`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let squareWidth = CGFloat(100)
    let squareHeight = CGFloat(100)

    @State private var bigger = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Color.green
                .frame(width: self.squareWidth, height: self.squareHeight)
                .scaleEffect(x: bigger ? 2 : 1, y: 1, anchor: .leading)
                .animation(.default)
            Button(action: {
                    self.bigger.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Click me!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem exactly the same. If I needed to apply several effects I should specify the anchor point for each of them, instead of specifying the anchor point on the view just one time. On `UIKit` I could write:

```
var myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
myView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5) //that is, the .leading of SwiftUI
```

Comment: I don't know if there is an option for changing the anchor point of an animation, But by adding a padding you can change the center of the animation.I tried  `.padding(.leading, bigger ? self.squareWidth : 0 )`  after `.animation(.default)` of your `Color.green` View.If that didn't solve your problem please a bit more specific about *applying several effects*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible, but your approach must change.

There is an implied, built-in centring of views in SwiftUI, which can be confusing.

The parent view is the one placing the content in the centre, recalculating the position of its subviews *each time* their frames change.

Embedding the VStack in a HStack and adding borders to both clearly shows this behaviour.

Also, note the `Spacer()`, which pushes the view to the left.

```
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Color.green
                    .frame(width: bigger ? self.squareWidth * 2 : self.squareWidth)
                    .frame(height: self.squareHeight)
                    .animation(.default)

                Button("Click me!") { self.bigger.toggle() }
            }.border(Color.black)

            Spacer()

        }.border(Color.red)
```

Using the `.layer.anchorPoint` in UIKit should have the same effect as using scaleEffect/offset/rotationEffect in SwiftUI, as it should affect the origin of the underlying geometry/texture which is being rendered by the GPU.

If you have a complex view (composed of multiple subviews) that needs the same scale effect, you can group them using a `Group { }` and use .scaleEffect on it.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now. And yes, as you said, this built-in centring of views is kinda confusing, your example is clear.